# PostgreSQL JSON object sum

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sum

I have a column with json data like this:

```
{
    "40593":[{"id":1,"amount":1}],
    "40594":[{"id":1,"amount":1},{"id":2,"amount":1}]
}
```

I want to calculate the sum from the amount property for the given id.
For the example above for id 1 I want to get 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the keys of the object, unnest the arrays, and then aggregate:

```
select
    (y.obj ->> 'id')::int id,
    sum((y.obj ->> 'amount')::int) total_amount
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(t.mycol) x(attr)
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.mycol -> x.attr) as y(obj)
group by (y.obj ->> 'id')::int
order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=329a70ce9a7fe0066f2d9ec2698c9c75)**:

```
id | total_amount
-: | -----------:
 1 |            2
 2 |            1
```